# python tkinter grid positioning

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm a newbie at Python and trying my first layout with grid.
What I really need is this layout:

[image: final layout]

My listing is:

```
1. root=Tk()
2. root.geometry("640x480")
3. root.title("Skroutz Parser")

#entryText=StringVar(root)
4. topFrame=Frame(root, bg='cyan', width = 640, height=80)
5. middleFrame=Frame(root,bg='gray2', width=640, height=400)
6. bottomFrame=Frame(root, bg='yellow', width = 640, height=50)

# layout all of the main containers
7. root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
8. root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

9. topFrame.grid(row=0)
10.middleFrame.grid(row=1)
11.bottomFrame.grid(row=2)

# layout middle container
12.middleFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
13.middleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

14.leftFrame=Frame(middleFrame, bg='green', width = 125, height=400)
15.rightFrame=Frame(middleFrame, bg='white', width = 515, height=400)

16.leftFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="n")
17.rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1)

18.buttonFeatured=Button(leftFrame, text='   Recommended    ', pady=5, .command=showRecommendedProductsResults)
19.buttonSkroutz=Button(leftFrame, text='Skroutz Products', pady=5, command=printSkroutzProducts)
20.buttonFeatured.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="n")
21.buttonSkroutz.grid(row=1, column=0)

22.entryText=StringVar()
23.entryMain=Entry(rightFrame,textvariable=entryText, bg="white")
24.entryMain.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,columnspan=5,sticky="w")

25.root.mainloop()
```

---

If i comment lines 18-24, then I get more or less the desired layout:

[image]

if I uncomment lines 18-21 (leaving commented lines 22-24) then I get this (strange black color on left frame):

[image]

and if I uncomment the rest of the lines....I get a mess!!!

[image]

I'm struggling two days now, but no luck....
Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a multi-line or single line text widget in there?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as is your code has redundant parts.

Comment: You have to structure your code better or things may get out of hand like this. OOP approach really makes you organize such scripts easier.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following code, I have made multiple changes that I lost track of:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("640x480")
root.title("Skroutz Parser")

#entryText=StringVar(root)
topFrame=Frame(root, bg='cyan', width = 640, height=80)
middleFrame=Frame(root,bg='gray2', width=640, height=400)
bottomFrame=Frame(root, bg='yellow', width = 640, height=50)

# layout all of the main containers
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

topFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew')
middleFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
bottomFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='ew')

# layout middle container
middleFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
middleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

leftFrame=Frame(middleFrame, bg='green', width = 125, height=400)
rightFrame=Frame(middleFrame, bg='white', width = 515, height=400)

leftFrame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
rightFrame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

leftFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
rightFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
rightFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

buttonFeatured=Button(leftFrame, text='   Recommended    ', pady=5)
buttonSkroutz=Button(leftFrame, text='Skroutz Products', pady=5)
buttonFeatured.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="new")
buttonSkroutz.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='new')

entryText=StringVar()
entryMain=Entry(rightFrame,textvariable=entryText, bg="white")
entryMain.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="new")

root.mainloop()
```

Now if you want larger text area you can either increase font size or you can instead have multi-line entry, `Text` which you can configure the size of.

You really should check out [structure question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17466561/7032856) though.

Answer (score 0):

This code will reproduce a GUI that matches the desired layout as displayed in the image.

I've used `import tkinter as tk` and included function `flexx` for control of row and column configurations. Apart from that code is virtually the same as original post.

Window is resizable.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def flexx(m, r = 0, c = 0, rw = 1, cw = 1):
    if r !=  None:
        m.rowconfigure(r, weight = rw)
    if c !=  None:
        m.columnconfigure(c, weight = cw)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Skroutz Parser")
flexx(root, r = 1)

topFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "cyan", width = 640, height = 80)
middleFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "gray2", width = 640, height = 400)
bottomFrame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "yellow", width = 640, height = 50)

topFrame.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)
middleFrame.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)
bottomFrame.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)

flexx(middleFrame, c = 1)

leftFrame = tk.Frame( middleFrame, bg = "green")
rightFrame = tk.Frame( middleFrame, bg = "white")
leftFrame.grid(sticky = tk.NS)
rightFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.NSEW)

flexx(leftFrame, rw = 0)
flexx(leftFrame, rw = 0, c = 1)
flexx(rightFrame, rw = 0)

buttonFeatured = tk.Button(leftFrame, text = "   Recommended    ", pady = 5) #, .command = showRecommendedProductsResults)
buttonSkroutz = tk.Button(leftFrame, text = "Skroutz Products", pady = 5) # , command = printSkroutzProducts)
buttonFeatured.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)
buttonSkroutz.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)

entryText = tk.StringVar(root, value = "Some text...")
entryMain = tk.Entry(rightFrame, textvariable = entryText,
                     justify = tk.CENTER, bg = "white",
                     borderwidth = 3, relief = tk.SOLID)
entryMain.grid(rowspan = 2, ipady = 50, sticky = tk.NSEW)

root.geometry("740x512")
root.mainloop()
```